# Laravel Redis Error

Tags: php, laravel, azure, redis, laravel-5

I have recently updated Laravel to 5.2 following the migration guide on Laravel main website.

However, it seems new predis driver does not support my Redis server; I am using Ms Azure built-in Redis Cache, so I don't have access to the configuration of Redis itself, they only give out SSl/non-SSl ports, ApiKey and an URL.

In particular, whenever running

```
php artisan queue:listen
```

I get the following error:

```
[Predis\Response\ServerException]  
  NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

How to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I have already set up REDIS_HOST, REDIS_PORT and REDIS_PASSWORD costants in my .env file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my test, it only occurs when the redis passowrd is empty or wrong which will make your application fail to authenticate from redis server on Azure.

Please double check the redis info you set in `.env` file. Which should be similar with:

```
REDIS_HOST=<your_redis_server_name>.redis.cache.windows.net
REDIS_PASSWORD=<your_reids_base64_encrypted_key_should_end_with_"=">
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Meanwhile, you can create a simple testing PHP script to verify your redistricting info:

```
$client = new Predis\Client([
    'scheme' => 'tcp',
    'host' => '<your_redis_server_name>.redis.cache.windows.net',
    'port' => 6379,
]);
$client->auth(<your_reids_base64_encrypted_key_should_end_with_"=">);
$client->set('foo', 'bar');
$bar = $client->get('foo');
echo $bar;
```